# What are the R numbers in the eSword NASB?

Tags: bible

Psalm 103:14 (NASB)
(14)  For He Himself knows our frame; **He** is mindful that we are **but** dust.

Here, **He** is R2 and **but** is R3. What do those R numbers that mean? Are they still Hebrew words?

[image]

The screenshot was taken from my NASB package in eSword.

Comment: Please links sourced website to your image! Your profile hints that you know how!

Comment: [Strong's Exhaustive Concordance](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ts1NgCRJY8cC&pg=PA1476&lpg=PA1476&dq=strong+h6083+R3&source=bl&ots=cyvZQG1WcX&sig=ACfU3U2NioaCrMYaMmj7H7Vu5NxmagcD-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifvaaR9fnnAhUBiFwKHdk7BBAQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=strong%20h6083%20R3&f=false) only displays H for hebrew and G for greek. I can only think that R1/R2/R3/N1 refer to what part of speech the word is (maybe ?).

Comment: I think you misascribe the R numbers to the preceding word. There is a gap between the end of the preceding word and the R number, but no gap between the R number and the following word. So, for example, R3 relates to "dust" not to "but". "He Himself" is a translation of a single Hebrew word, H1941. R1 is prefixed to it.

Comment: I notice that R1 comes first, then R2 and then R3. Possibly the R numbers are references to something in the book or site you are looking at. N1 night be a note. Do other verses follow a pattern e.g. if there is an R2 is there always an R1 earlier in the verse?

Comment: It is the NASB in eSword.

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer from a forum question (post #2 by Bradley S. Cobb): [NASB + marking's what are they for](http://www.biblesupport.com/topic/1522-nasb-markings-what-are-they-for/)

> the N stands for footnote. the R stands for cross-reference. the notes/references are in the NASB commentary file.